# Understanding CSS child selectors

Tags: html, css

I am after some knowledge (Which I have looked up the documentation and still cannot wrap my head around it). I have put together some simple css to get an idea of what it is supposed to do or behave?

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            Yes
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I have put together some very simple html with some very simple css.

```
body{
    margin:0;
}

.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: red;  
}

.navbar{
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A0A0A0;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.navbar > logo{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

So what I am trying to understand or achieve to understand is what (if anything) is .navbar > logo doing? What I want it to do is change style of some kind. I am just trying to wrap my head around this as I wan to advance my CSS knowledge.

Here is a fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/KvqSH/)

Please note this isn't for anything specific or project wise so I am not asking for somebody to help me I just want some simple explanation as to how to use these correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.navbar > logo
```

isn't doing anything because you don't have a `<logo>` element.

Because `logo` is a class, it should be `.logo`:

```
.navbar > .logo
```

The difference between:

```
.navbar .logo
.navbar > .logo
```

> The first selector above is a decendant selector. It will select any list items that are anywhere underneath an unordered list in the markup structure. The list item could be buried three levels deep within other nested lists, and this selector will still match it. The second selector above is a child combinator selector. This means it will only select list items that are direct children of an unordered list. In otherwords, it only looks one level down the markup structure, no deeper. So if there was another unordered list nested deeper, the list item children of it will not be targeted by this selector.

[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Taking what you know now, `.navbar > .logo` wouldn't work. It would have to be `.navbar > .container > .logo` or just `.navbar .logo`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the  quick response but even by changing that (typo) it dosn't change anything - I am after some more knowledge and a working example of changing its behaviour so I can see who it works?

Comment: And to further add to this, the > selector is the "direct descendant selector" which means it will only apply to elements with the class ".logo" which are direct descendants of the element with the ".navbar" class. Edit: see you have updated the answer :-)

Comment: Perfect - this makes sense to me!

Comment: Yes put the dot in for .logo and then maybe try the following HTML to see what is meant:

<div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
        Yes
    </div> 
 <div class="container">
     <div class="logo">
         No
     </div>        
 </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

```
.navbar > .container > .logo
```

**or**

```
.navbar .logo
```

Your mistakes:

- in your case you should use class selector `.logo` instead of element `logo`
- `.logo` is not a child of `.navbar`, it is a descendant, so you should use one of the examples above (using descendant parenthesis or child parenthesis through `.container` element)

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KvqSH/1/)